# gem to track the number of hits the site get without login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

I am building a site on Rails framework on ec2. I am following Lean Startup approach.

Question:

1. Is there a gem/ way to track the number of hits the site have?
2. Also the time a user spend on the site?

I do not want/ be pushy to the users to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a gem called Sliding Stats. Its a small little piece of code you can plug into any Rack enabled Ruby web app (any Ruby web-framework can work with Rack these days) to give you an idea of what's going on without having to look into referrer logs etc. Here's a github page for this gem https://github.com/vidarh/sliding-stats

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tracking tool like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) or [Piwik](http://www.piwik.org).

I don't know of any gems, but you could count page hits by using filters in your `ApplicationController` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687901/is-there-a-rails-gem-for-tracking-page-views).