# Rails 3 - exist any gem for counting page views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tracking, counter, pageviews, visited

I wanna to add to my blog a counter for displaying, how many times was an article displayed. I would like to solve it through ruby (not GA or something like that).
Is available any gem that do this task (also with checking IP address and the time of latest reading of article) or I have to implement by myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302989/gem-to-track-the-number-of-hits-the-site-get-without-login

Comment: @Pf. privacy and session data. Also you may want to plug this in with other information on your site, which is harder to do if you need to export the GA stats, and use only the filters they provide

Comment: It's not that hard, just place a before filter on the ApplicationController that records the browser histories. I think it's enough to fulfill the task.

Comment: I did it in the similar way + added a checking of the last time, when a visitor went a page

Answer (score 0):

There's one used by thousands of people at http://www.seologic.com/webmaster-tools/counters. Source code is available at https://github.com/ivanoblomov/hit_counter.